# Drawing small sprite to large bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3

[I found this question on Adobe's forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/6013921), but I'm not happy with the answer there:

> I have a sprite circSprite that I draw on a large bitmap drawingBitmap.
>
> ```
> drawingBitmapData = new BitmapData(800, 600, true,0);
> drawingBitmap = new Bitmap(drawingBitmapData);
> stage.addChild(drawingBitmap);
>
> var circSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
> circSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000,0);
> circSprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,160,160);
> circSprite.graphics.endFill();
> circSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF00FF,1);
> circSprite.graphics.drawCircle(40,40,40);
> circSprite.graphics.endFill();
>
> var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();
>
> drawingBitmapData.drawWithQuality(circSprite,mat,null,null, null,true,StageQuality.MEDIUM);
> ```
>
> I would like to move the circSpirte to a different position ( 100,100 ) - how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use blitting. If that's the case there are basically two routes to go. You can either use the bitmap data `draw()` ( looks like you are using `drawWithQuality()` )or `copyPixels()`. `copyPixels()` is many times faster than using `draw()`, if you are planning on moving your objects around a lot, I'd recommend going the `copyPixels()` route. And here is how I would do that:

You should store a `BitmapData` representation of your sprite so you only have to call `draw()` once.

```
//create the BitmapData variable for your sprite somewhere in member access.
private var spriteBmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData( circSprite.width, circSprite.height );
//draw after the circSprite is created
spriteBmd.draw( circSprite );

//then wherever you are doing the movement to a new position
drawingBitmapData.unlock();

//fill rect here can be replaced with a copyPixels of your background, but
//this just redraws the background to "clear" the blitting, this can be 
//optimized with a technique known as "dirty rectangles" which I'll link a tutorial to
drawingBitmapData.fillRect( stage.getBounds(stage), 0 );

//copy our sprite to a new destination point ( see new Point( 100, 100 ) )
drawingBitmapData.copyPixels( spriteBmd, spriteBmd.rect, new Point( 100, 100 ) );

//done blitting, lock the bitmapdata
drawingBitmapData.lock();
```

The other way state in the previous answer looks something like this, but if you are doing a lot of transformations this will be quite a bit slower:

```
var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();
mat.translate( 100, 100 );  
drawingBitmapData.draw( circSprite, mat );
```

Here's a link to a tutorial explaining blitting which talks about "Dirty Rectangles" (noted in my comments):

[AS3 Blitting Tutorial](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-what-is-blitting--gamedev-2247)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the matrix that you created to perform a translation on the object, I would recommend that you read the [documentation on Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) but it goes like this:

```
var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();
mat.translate(100,100);
```